# Notebook for developers

Tags: laptop, linux, development

I am a computer science student with specialization in machine learning and I need a new notebook. I work inside most of the time, but I take my notebook to presentations / collaborative development / lectures quite often.

### Past Notebook

I am currently using the [Acer TravelMate 5744Z](http://martin-thoma.com/review-des-acer-travelmate-5744z/#tocAnchor-1-1). It has several pain points:

- Only 4 GB RAM
- No SSD
- Weak CPU: I compile LaTeX documents VERY often. So single-threaded CPU power does matter to me.
- Too heavy
- Battery lasts for about 2h (3.7h according to the specs)
- 15.6" screen which I like very much

And some good points

- Everything works out of the box on Linux
- It's VERY silent! (29,6 - 32,0 dB(A) in idle mode, according to [notebookcheck](http://www.notebookcheck.com/Test-Acer-TravelMate-5744Z-P624G50Mikk-Notebook.71588.0.html))
- Sturdy enough to be put into my backpack without any protective case
- The size of the keyboard is comfortable. I don't need the numpad, though.

All in all, I was happy with that notebook. However, as the battery seems / the power supply unit seems to have problems now. Together with the other issues, I think it is time for a new notebook, as I use it many hours every single day.

### Hard Requirements

- Has to be available in Germany
- Has to work with Linux
- Not more than 2000 Euro
- At least 8 GB RAM
- SSD with at least 120 GB
- Not heavier than 2.5 kg (inclusive battery, of course!)
- Battery has to last for at least 5 hours under random web surfing.
- Resolution of at least 1366x768
- Not more than 16" screen, not less than 13.3" (I'm not too sure if I will like small screens, though. And I'm not sure how I can figure that out without buying such a notebook)
- Connectivity

  - WLAN (which has to work out-of-the-box for Linux!)
  - At least 3 USB ports
- Has to be silent under normal work load (e.g. surfing random web pages)

### Positive

The follwing is positive, but I don't need it

- +++++

  - D-SUB connector (VGA connector)
  - Good keyboard
  - German keyboard layout
  - SD card reader
  - at least 256 GB of storage
- +++

  - RJ45 slot for network
  - DVD player
  - Matte display
  - NVidia GPU which can be used for machine learning
  - Less than 2.0 kg
  - A review by a developer who uses Linux
- ++

  - USB 3.0 / USB 3.1
- +

  - Aluminium case
  - Backlit keyboard
  - Webcam / microphone
  - Bluetooth
- Neutral / I don't care

  - Numpad
  - Blue-Ray player

### Additional information

I think I'm able to add RAM to the notebook by myself. I did so several times with desktop computers. However, if it doesn't make a price difference of more than 40 Euro I would prefer to let it be done by others.

### Related question

My notebook (kind of) still works. I could wait for 2 more months without problems. Is there any benefit of waiting? Do prices significantly differ after Christmas? Are there new interesting notebooks being released?

Comment: Would you be alright with hybrid storage of say, 128/64 GB of SSD and 1 TB of HDD? If yes, what if the HDD was external?

Comment: @Alpha3031 You're right, I don't need 256 of internal storage. If I need more, I can use my external HDD. I've edited my question. However, I'm not willing to go below 120 GB of internal storage. - About the SSD / hybrid storage: I want an SSD because of the reading performance. I've noticed that I spend a significant amount of time to wait for my computer booting / reading several GB of data into the memory. I would have to look it up how hybrid storage performs compared to SSD. I guess it would be ok.

Comment: You could consider a [Dell Inspiron](http://www.dell.com/uk/p/inspiron-17-7737/pd). I've not checked all features against your specs, but I have an older Inspiron which I use for heavy development and it still works great 4 years on.

Comment: Recommend against laptops with Broadcom wireless chipsets, can be troublesome under Linux (Arch in my case)

Answer (score 3):

## Apple MacBook Pro 13-inch with Retina display

### Positive:

- Available in Germany
- Works with OS X and Linux
- 1649€ with the specs you want
- 8 GB DDR3 RAM
- 256 GB SSD (really fast: over 1.5 GB/s read and write)
- 1.58 kg
- 10 hours of web surfing
- 2560x1600 display
- 13.3-inch screen
- Wi-Fi ac (over 1.3 Gbit/s; I have tested it myself)
- Silent under normal workload
- D-SUB/VGA (via Thunderbolt adapter)
- Good keyboard
- German keyboard
- Backlit keyboard
- SD card reader
- RJ45 (via Thunderbolt adapter)
- Anti-reflective display
- USB 3.0
- Aluminium case
- Webcam / microphone
- Bluetooth 4.0

### Negative:

- Only 2 USB ports (extendable via Thunderbolt; never was an issue for me)
- No DVD/Blu-ray player (never needed one)
- No Matte display (anti-reflective)
- No NVIDIA GPU
- No numpad
- No USB 3.1

I don't think there will be any special pricing in the near future. But go to a Media Markt, Saturn, e.g. or look at notebooksbilliger.de or similar for special pricing.

If you have any questions: I am german and own this Notebook (Late 2013). Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Ooh, nice. Welcome to Hardware recommendations.

Comment: Which linux distribution(s) do you run on your MBP? Have you had negative experiences with some distributions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble finding an official [Ubuntu Certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) or Shipped-with-linux computers with shipping to Germany, so I'm going to reccomend the Lenovo Y50-70.

### Lenovo Y50-70 [(Amazon.de)](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B00U1PP3FQ/ref=twister_B00YXZU29M?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1) !!C- (52.6%)

<sup>**2 potential problems (marked by (~))** Score calculated by number of (+) divided by total possible (+)</sup>

- Available in Germany, via Amazon.de with free shipping **(+)**
- Is not Ubuntu certified, but there [have](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=239&t=202980) been [multiple](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/lenovo-ideapad-y50-review.html) people who have [successfully](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/y50-linux-thread.756405/) installed [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/873056/linux-mint-17-1-lenovo-y50-70-installing-getting-gtx860m-to-work-with-nvidia-dr) on the Y50-70, though exact hardware configurations may vary (Most models used were using the 860M) and the installation was not always without trouble. **(~)**
- The DOS/256 GB SSD version linked is €949.00 **(++)**
- It has 8GB of DDR3 SDRAM, potentially upgradable to 16GB in the future **(+)**
- Weight is 2.4 kg **(+)**
- Battery is claimed to last 5 hours. This is probably under Windows, so you may need a battery efficent distro and try to limit display brightness and CPU/GPU voltage **(~)**
- Model has a 15.6" 1080p IPS display **(++)**
- 2 USB 3.0, 1 USB 2.0 **(+)**
- Intel WiFi cards (Wireless-AC 3160) are generally supported **(+)**
- [The fans shut off at low load](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y50-70-GTX-960M-FHD-Notebook-Review.145896.0.html) **(+)**

<sup>**10/12** The above section accounts for 60% of the total score</sup>

- The GTX 960M has a VGA port **(5)**
- Keyboard is fairly standard for a gaming notebook this size **(3)**
- The keyboard is a standard QWERTY layout **(0)**
- 4 in 1 card reader **(5)**
- 256 GB SSD **(5)**

<sup>**18/25** The above each has a maximum score out of 5</sup>

- [Apparently, it does have a LAN slot](http://laptopmedia.com/review/lenovo-y50-gtx-960m-review-the-slimmed-down-powerhouse-got-even-better/) **(3)**
- There might be an external DVD drive for driver installation, but I wouldn't count on it. No internal ODD **(0)**
- The 1080p version has a matte display **(3)**
- Nvidia GTX 960M. Mid range, quite speedy, but not a workstation card. 4 GB VRAM and 80 GB/s, competitive with a Quadro M2000M **(2)**
- Not light enough **(0)**
- [Someone has reviewed a older version using linux, but it's a rather small addendum](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/lenovo-ideapad-y50-review.html) **(+)**

<sup>**9/18** The above each has a maximum score out of 3</sup>

- 2 USB 3.0, no USB 3.1 **(+)**

<sup>**1/2**</sup>

- Partially Aluminum **(0.5)**
- Red backlit keyboard **(+)**
- Webcam and microphone built in **(+)**
- Bluetooth **(+)**

<sup>**3.5/4** Total for section 2: **31.5/49 (64%)**</sup>